# modifying character variable contents based on lookup table in SAS

Tags: replace, sas, recode

`HAVE` is a wide dataset with names stored in the variables `name1-name250`. Here are the first two obs and several vars:

```
episode name1           name2           name3           name4           name5         ...
121     DETWEILER.TJ.M  BLUMBERG.MIKEY  GRISWOLD.GUS.N      
451     BOB.KING        KID.HUSTLER     FINSTER.MS      PRICKLEY.PETEY  GRISWOLD.GUS
...
```

Some of the names need to be corrected. The corrections are stored in the dataset `FIXES`:

```
goodname        badname
DETWEILER.TJ    DETWEILER.TJ.M
GRISWOLD.GUS    GRISWOLD.GUS.N
```

I simply need to find the `badname` from `FIXES` that appear in `HAVE` and replace them with `goodname`. I currently loop through `name1-name250` in a data step for each row in `FIXES` to accomplish this:

```
data WANT;
set HAVE;

array name {*} name1-name250;

do i=1 to dim(name);

         if name{i} = "DETWEILER.TJ.M" then name{i} = "DETWEILER.TJ";
    else if name{i} = "GRISWOLD.GUS.N" then name{i} = "GRISWOLD.GUS";
    /*manually add other corrections from FIXES dataset*/
    else name{i} = name{i};

end;

run;
```

This feels really inefficient. What is a better way?

Comment: Why not convert your dataset to have one record per episode/name and then you can just merge (join) the two tables without having to loop over an array of variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a simple exact match translation like that a FORMAT is a simple way to implement it. You can convert your "lookup" data into a format.

```
data fixes ;
  input goodname :$30. badname :$30. ;
cards; 
DETWEILER.TJ DETWEILER.TJ.M
GRISWOLD.GUS GRISWOLD.GUS.N
;

data format ;
  retain fmtname '$FIXNAME' ;
  set fixes end=eof;
  rename badname=start goodname=label;
run;

proc format cntlin=format;
run;
```

Then just use the format to convert the names.

```
data want;
  set have;
  array name name1-name5;
  do over name;
    name=put(name,$fixname30.);
  end;
run;
```

Result:

```
episode    name1               name2            name3            name4            name5

  121      DETWEILER.TJ    BLUMBERG.MIKEY    GRISWOLD.GUS
  451      BOB.KING        KID.HUSTLER       FINSTER.MS      PRICKLEY.PETEY    GRISWOLD.GUS
```